# Power Spectral Density from Accelerometer data

Tags: signal-processing, fft, spectral-density

I have an accelerometer data i.e. AccX, AccY and AccZ.

I am looking for an algorithm to compute Power Spectral Density from this data. I know the following:

```
F = fft (s);
```

where "s" is the input signal and fft is fast fourier transform.

```
PSD = (1/length(s)) * F * conj(F);
```

I need to know that whether this `s` should be acceleration-time series or position-time series?

Comment: Seems to me that NASA uses the acceleration:http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19970034695.pdf But read this doc for yourself, I am not an expert here.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are interested in. If you want the power spectral density of the acceleration time-series, then `s` must be the acceleration time-series itself and not the position time-series.
Note however that the estimate of the PSD based on that simple algorithm you wrote (called "periodogram") may be insufficient in many cases, to get a realistic estimate of the real PSD.
The topic is huge, and literature extensive. You can start from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) or, if you want a suggestion on a good (but rather tough) book, [Percival and Walden](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Spectral_Analysis_for_Physical_Applicati.html?id=86IOtxblyQcC&redir_esc=y). To provide more detailed info, one would need to know much more in detail what you have to do from a physical point of view.